# Get the Highest Value in Livecode

Tags: max, livecode, highest

I have three variables with the following values...

```
put 10 into var1
put 7 into var2
put 2 into var3
```

How to get the highest value? For this example, I want to return 10 and display that "10 is the highest number". How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite standard in any programming language.

```
put max(var1,var2,var3) into myMax
```